# Finding the path for a Python module without importing it

Tags: python

How can I find the path for a Python module without importing it?

It seems like it should be obvious but I can't find a function to do this. (Yes I double-checked the docs for `imp`).

Note: I can't import the module. 
Also this is a python2 specific issue, so I can't use `importlib.find_loader`.

---

update per comment: 
In python3 this can be done with `importlib.find_loader` which returns an object with a `path` property, which works for packages and files (unlike `imp.find_module`).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to find the path of a module without importing it, what exactly merits the downvotes?

Comment: Some background would make your question more understandable. Or if you know how to do it in Python 3, post that code. Why can't you import the module?

Comment: @noa I had a stray python3 module loading into python2 on import instead of the one I wanted to load, which was causing syntax errors and I didn't know which path it was on. It's basically not a common use case and I just reverted to shell `find` piped to `grep`, but I thought there should be an accessible function to do this.

Comment: Yeah, it's a good question. I'm not too surprised there isn't a way though. You could always run python3, import it, and print the path.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
import imp
print imp.find_module("mymodule")
```

Comment: That's only works for files and not for package paths..